# Forces and masses don't add up in Gazebo 7

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a 5kg sphere and apply 100N of force in the +Z direction. Assuming lim t->0, the sphere should leave the ground at ~20m/s vertically and reach a height of ~41m. Instead it remains stationary. It will only hop if I apply outrageous amounts of force (1000N).

Does anybody know what's causing this? Even if the impulse is over half a second it should leave the ground. I see this even when I create a sphere primitive using the GUI, and apply force using the GUI.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18940/forces-and-masses-don%27t-add-up-in-gazebo-7/) by [smorad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4914/smorad/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smorad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4914/smorad/) on 2018-04-08**:
Are there others who are seeing this? I'm not sure if this is a problem with the engine or just how it's setup on my machine.

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2018-04-08**:
I suspect the impulse is over way less than half a second. Probably one simulation time step.

**Comment by [smorad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4914/smorad/) on 2018-04-09**:
Whether 100N is spread out over 500ms or 1ms I should still see the ball move vertically, right? What happens when you put a primitive sphere in the simulation and apply 100N in the +Z direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As @Peter Mitrano suggests, the **[force is applied over only 1 simulation time step](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=apply_force_torque)**, resulting in a **small impulse** and therefore a **very small change in velocity**.

---

When I run Gazebo simulator, the default max time (step) size is 0.001 *(1 ms)*

F = m * a
v = a * t
v(t) = v(t=0) + 1/m * integral(F(t), 0, t)

If we assume a constant F across the time step, then
**v(t) = v(t=0) + (F * t)/m**

---

*Given:*
v(t=0) = 0
F = 100 N  *(F > Fgravity)*
t = 0.001 s *(1 simulation time step)*
m = 5 kg

v(0.001) = 0 + (100 * 0.001)/5
**v(0.001) = 0.02 m/s** or **2 cm/s**

---

Throwing in the effects of gravity, we can determine *(roughly)* that the 5 kg sphere in your example should - in theory - reach a maximum vertical *(+z)* height of 0.01 m *(1 cm)* and return to a height of 0 m after 0.02 s *(20 ms)*.

---

Physics: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/Lesson-1/Momentum-and-Impulse-Connection

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3